# Passenger 6 failing to launch - Cannot connect to TCP socket

Tags: phusion-passenger

I'm trying to use the new Generic Language Support in Passenger 6.  On development, I can spawn my demo Go app as follows:

```
passenger start --app-start-command 'env PORT=$PORT ./main'
```

Everything works fine.

On my server (running Debian Stretch) I am getting the following error when I try to run the exact same command:

> [ E 2019-01-02 20:17:13.7593 7371/Tr
>   age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for
>   application (...): An operating system error occurred while preparing
>   to spawn an application process: Cannot connect to TCP socket
>   '127.0.0.1:5000': Cannot assign requested address (errno=99)

I get the same error when I run the command as `root`.  However, I CAN run the go binary directly (`env PORT=5000 ./main`).

Running `netstat -ntulp` before and after trying to launch passenger reveals nothing running on `127.0.0.1:5000`.  After launching passenger, my server IS listening on `:::5000`.  So, there seems to be a problem with Passenger binding to an empty IPv4 port.

I'll also mention that I'm able to successfully launch rails apps with Passenger on this same server.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Is your `lo` interface up?

Comment: Yes, it is: `lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is related to this [issue #2144](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2144) on github.  I missed it at first, since the original symptom they had noticed was a CPU spike.

There's a [branch](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/tree/GH-2144_GLS_handshake_issues) with a fix - building Passenger from that branch solved the issue for me.

Comment: And, the fix is now in the latest release of Passenger as well.  No need to build from source any more.